# how to enable bzip2 compression on centos

Tags: php, centos, bzip2

I need to enable bzip2 compression on a centOS server. Let me walk you through what I did so far:

When running `composer install` I get the following errors:

```
Problem 1
  - Installation request for jakoch/phantomjs-installer 2.1.1-p08 -> satisfiable by jakoch/phantomjs-installer[2.1.1-p08].
  - jakoch/phantomjs-installer 2.1.1-p08 requires ext-bz2 * -> the requested PHP extension bz2 is missing from your system.
Problem 2
  - jakoch/phantomjs-installer 2.1.1-p08 requires ext-bz2 * -> the requested PHP extension bz2 is missing from your system.
  - josh/php-phantomjs v4.6.2 requires jakoch/phantomjs-installer 2.1.1-p08 -> satisfiable by jakoch/phantomjs-installer[2.1.1-p08].
  - Installation request for josh/php-phantomjs v4.6.2 -> satisfiable by josh/php-phantomjs[v4.6.2].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
  - /usr/local/lib/php.ini
  - /usr/local/lib/php.conf.d/50-webapps.ini
```

I uncommented the extension line of bz2 in php.ini file:

```
extension=bz2
```

and restarted apache. After running `php --ini` I get the following message:

```
Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/bz2 (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/bz2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)...
```

Which is true because there is no `bz2.so` file inside `extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/` directory.

I searched a lot about how to install bzip2 extension for php but could not find any solutions. Also `bzip2` is already installed on the machine.

I was thinking maybe finding a `bz2.so` file and putting in `extensions` directory could fix the problem but again could not find the file either!

Any idea how to enable this extension (and others like php soap) on server?

Comment: `sudo yum install bzip2` maybe?

Comment: @AbraCadaver `bzip2` is already installed on the server. I wonder maybe php extensions are different from local packages.

Comment: Did you search available packages for a bz2 or bzip2 library for use with PHP? Did you browse available packages for available PHP extensions?

Comment: I have never used it, but found this https://www.php.net/manual/en/bzip2.installation.php  Looks like PHP needs to be compiled with bz2 support.

Comment: Can you verify if this server utilizes cPanel w/EasyApache and if so, which version of each

Comment: @BA_Webimax Direct admin v.1.57.1 is installed on this server so EasyApache is not availavle.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks for the feedback. I've checked that before, but since this is a production server I'm not sure compiling php is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

this should work on PHP v7.3. 
in php.ini please look for 
"ExtensionList"
many extensions are defined there, 
just add **extension=php_bz2.dll** at the end of the list you see.
as you need to check if php_bz2.dll file was available in the PHP extensions folder .....\PHP\v7.3\ext\
if not, just let me know, so i could upload it for you.
Then restart apache